# How to check if a go app is buildable?

Tags: go, compilation

I write some code then build the app to an output file, but sometimes I just want to check if the app is buildable, i.e. has no errors and produces a compiled output, but without actually writing the output file.

I tried this variant and it seemed to work:

```
go build -o /dev/null myapp
```

But I suspect there must be a more "official" Go way to check if it can build.

Please advise!

Comment: Why not use the tests to check the build?

Answer (score 3):

To check if a package or app is buildable, `go build` is the "official" way.

What you did is the easiest way. In my opinion, you should stick to it. Alternatively you may do:

```
go build -o delme && rm delme
```

But it's somewhat slower as it has to write the result which is then deleted, but this solution is platform independent (as `/dev/null` does not exist on windows).

When building a command (`main` package), by definition `go build` will create and leave the result in the *current working directory*. If you build a "normal" package (non-`main`), the results will be *discarded*. See details here: [What does go build build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612611/what-does-go-build-build)

So if it bothers you that you have to use the `-o /dev/null` param or manually delete the result, you may "transform" your `main` package to a non-`main`, let's call it `main2`. And add a new `main` package which should do nothing else but import and call `main2.Main()`. Building the `main2` package will not leave any files behind.

E.g. `myapp/main.go`:

```
package main

import "myapp/main2"

func main() { main2.Main() }
```

`myapp/main2/main2.go`:

```
// Every content you originally had in main.go

package main2

func Main() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to check if a go app is buildable?

As I understand your question, you wanted to see if the file you're editing has no error.

then you can use [vim-go plugin](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) for vim.

And then setup your .vimrc for creating the shortcut :

```
"shortcut for vim-go
au FileType go nmap <leader>r <Plug>(go-run)
au FileType go nmap <leader>b <Plug>(go-build)
au FileType go nmap <leader>t <Plug>(go-test)
au FileType go nmap <leader>c <Plug>(go-coverage)
```

I use this as my daily work life when I want to see my file has no error I just type `\+b`. and then it will output the error without typing `go build` in the terminal.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be [`gofmt -e my_file.go`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16863226/6309) on all files, but:

- that would not scale well
- This doesn't actually report all errors that `go build` might.

Meaning: `go build -o /dev/null` might still be the more thorough approach.

For just validating syntax and structure: [see `gotype`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gotype)

Answer (score 0):

I use [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and I've found it to be the better than Sublime when it comes to Go with [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go) extension.
When I save the document, it formats it well. It shows the the errors as I write code with the help of [golint](https://github.com/golang/lint) making development very manageable.

You can also use golint separately just like gofmt.
You can also try go vet. There are debates going on around what to use when but I'd just advise to use both if you can.